# Script to log a list of the path and file name of what was changed

Tags: powershell

I want to change the creation date on a various folders/files recursively. I have managed to get a simple powershell script to do this. However, the log file that is created only says true on several lines, depending on how many changes where made. What I would like is for the log file to list the file path and name of the file that was actually changed.

Below is the simple script I have that does the change but no details log file:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse G:\ | % {$_.CreationTime = '10/10/2014 15:00'}  | Out-File "c:\pslog.txt"
```

Please help as I am very new to powershell so the simpler the code the better.

Regards,

Mark

Comment: This may help you. https://gist.github.com/pjmagee/5659973

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `$_.CreationTime = '10/10/2014 15:00'`, the status of the operation is returned, so a bunch of `True`s just means that the new CreationTime assignment succeeded

To get the file path, hide the assignment and drop `$_.FullName` into the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse G:\ | % {($_.CreationTime = '10/10/2014 15:00')|Out-Null; $_.FullName }  | Out-File "C:\pslog.txt"
```

However, it might be useful to get the FileName along with the result, so that you can assess whether some of the files failed the assignment

You say you'd like some simple code, but compact one-liners does not equal "simple", and you might find that you learn a lot more from verbose code.

Let's split it into multiple statements for a better overview:

```
# Get the files
$gFiles = Get-ChildItem -recurse G:\ 
# Loop through them all
$gFiles | ForEach-Object {
    # Set the creation date without returning any output
    ($_.CreationTime = '10/10/2014 15:00') |Out-Null
    # Test if the previous operation was successful:
    if($?)
    {
        # Success, create an object containing the Path and status
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "FilePath" = $_.FullName
            "FileSize" = $_.Length
            "Result"   = "Success"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        # Success, create an object containing the Path and status
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "FilePath" = $_.FullName
            "FileSize" = $_.Length
            "Result"   = "Failed"
        }
    }
# Export the objects containing the result to a .CSV file
} |Export-Csv -LiteralPath "C:\pslog.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Now, C:\pslog.csv contains two semicolon-separated columns with appropriate headers for "Result" and "FilePath"

The `FileSize` property will be in number of bytes, but you could change it to KB or MB with:

```
"FileSize" = $_.Length / 1KB
"FileSize" = $_.Length / 1MB
```

Comment: I have tried to run the larger script above but get a error repeating itself:    Exception setting "CreationTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.Date"."At c:\users\mak.fidler\desktop\data2.ps1:6 char:5          there is a little bit more text but believe this part I have included is pointing to what is causing the issue but I cannot work it out. I am a complete ps novice so any help will be great

Comment: My mistake, script updated. It tried to assign `'10/10/2014 15:00' |Out-Null` to CreationTime, instead of piping the output from the assignment to Out-Null

Comment: Glad you're able to solve it. Please accept the answer if it answers your questions

Comment: I jave just been informed that this log file also needs to show the folder/file size of each, could you please advise what I would need to add to the script to have the log file show these details

Comment: I have tried using the "FileSize" = $_.Length / 1MB but the log still shows size in bytes.

Comment: I have tried running the script now on the production server and it fails with the following output:

Comment: Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'in'.
At C:\date.ps1:2 char:24
+ $gFiles = Get-ChildItem <<<<  -recurse F:\Mac Data\Studio\Work in Progress\MULTIYORK\D3328 Newsletter\Images
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Export-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter

Comment: name 'LiteralPath'.
At C:\date.ps1:25 char:27
+ } |Export-Csv -LiteralPath <<<<  "c:\pslog.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Force

Comment: Sorry for the messy above replies just I don't know how to add a screen shot of the error